# using Html.Encode in Razor

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following sample code in a razor view on a MVC4 sample project:

```
<p>@((@Model == null) ? "<unknow man>" : @Model.ClientName)</p>
<p>
    @if (@Model == null)
    {
        @Html.Encode("<unknow man>")
    }
    else
    {  
        @Model.ClientName;
    }
</p>
```

The output is a little bit odd for me...

In **Internet Explorer** I see:

```
<p>&lt;unknow man&gt;</p>
<p>&amp;lt;unknow man&amp;gt;</p>
```

In **Chrome**:

```
<p>​<unknow man>​</p>
​<p>​&lt;unknow man&gt;</p>​
```

And what is the most incredible (for me) is that finally I have the same visual output:

```
<unknow man>

&lt;unknow man&gt;
```

I wanted to display, however, this one in HTML:

```
<p>&lt;unknow man&gt;</p>
<p>&lt;unknow man&gt;</p>
```

and this one to the user:

```
<unknow man>

<unknow man>
```

## PS

I found a solution, finally, to display properly the string, like this

```
    @if (@Model == null)
    {
        @("<unknow man>")
    }
```

*But who can explain me the difference for the HTML.Encode in browsers, and why this didn't work like coded in the first example?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<p>@((@Model == null) ? @Html.Raw("&lt;unknow man&gt;") : @Model.ClientName)</p>
<p>
    @if (@Model == null)
    {
        <text>&lt;unknow man&gt;</text>
    }
    else
    {  
        @Model.ClientName;
    }
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, however, I don't need the `<text>` node... see my update

Comment: @Serge the text node will not been rendered

Comment: thanks, a interesting variant, i tested, it works... see also my solution how about the Encode, why it didn't work?

Comment: @Serge: There will be two encodings: Html.Encode will done &lt;unknow man&gt; and @ will reencode your string so the & of &lt; and &gt; will be &amp;

Comment: if i put just Html.Encode (without @) I have no output at all..., So, you are trying to say that we can't use here Html.Encode function?